# Can I convert a community created in VisualForce Pages to Lightning bolt theme?

Tags: community, lightning-community

I have created a community using the 'Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce pages' (AKA Classic).

We would like to migrate that community to a Lightning Theme (mainly the 'Partner Central' theme.
Is it possible?
Or I can only recreate a new community with the new Theme.

Comment: I think this can't really be migrated though you could surface the VF pages in the lightning community, the look and feel might not be ideal. That would save work if there is a lot of logic built into the VF pages.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_template_change.htm&type=5), it is possible to change Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce based community to a Lightning community template.

> If you use the Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce template, you can change your template to a Lightning community template or any installed Lightning Bolt Solution in Community Builder.

However during the migration your customizations may be lost and that you will need to address those accordingly. E.g., your VF pages need to be updated to Community builder pages. Also the URL, branding, etc. changes during the migration.

Take a look at [Considerations for Changing Your Community Template](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_template_considerations.htm&type=5) documentation for more details around this topic.